# Is it fine to put custom data in the apps Info.plist file?

Tags: iphone

For example, the website URL and other stuff that wants to be linked at runtime with the app? I find that info.plist is a good place for that. But maybe it is not allowed or causes trouble...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* it is fine, but the common practice is to create an extra plist for these custom stuff.